# HTML5 Imports not working

Tags: html

I have been searching a way to include html files into another html file...for example i have 3 html files... 1) header.html 2) content.html 3) footer.html... and i would like to include the header.html and the footer.html inside the content.html so i could create a multiple websites, include the header and footer, and if i have to change something to header and footer to be affected to all websites. I have read about imports in html file which i include my file like this

```
<link rel="import" href="header.html">
```

I have tried it and its not working. Is the import supported by the browsers?  If yes how would you make it work?

**I am looking for a similar way like php include, but for html.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct to do this is through server side pages includes or through JavaScript.

PHP example:

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>Welcome to my home page!</h1>
<p>Some text.</p>
<p>Some more text.</p>
<?php include 'footer.php';?>

</body>
</html>
```

Javascript Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE ) {
           if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
               document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
           }
           else if (xmlhttp.status == 400) {
              alert('There was an error 400');
           }
           else {
               alert('something else other than 200 was returned');
           }
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "header.html", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Javascript with JQuery Library:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "header.html",
    success: function(data){
      $("myDiv").html(data.responseText);
    }
});
```

If you don't want to get your hands dirty in js you can do the following using a script provided by w3schools:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3data.js"></script>

<body>

<div w3-include-html="header.html"></div> 

<script>
w3IncludeHTML();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks Zubair the W3schools solution is working great however is it safe to use it? Is it being used from other developers?

Comment: Yes, you can download the source code at the following `http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3data.js`. Review and host locally in your filesystem and include it from there.

Answer (score 1):

That's impossible. You can't include an HTML page into another, or you need to use PHP include()/require() function.

Else, you can load dynamically any page with AJAX and append the output to your main page, like this (here I use jQuery) :

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajax({
            url: 'page.html',
            success: function(content) {
                document.body.innerHTML += content;
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

(Note that you should add an 'error' event etc. etc. it's just an easy exemple)

Answer (score 1):

Well my answer is other more easy way. I used JQuery and files of html5 and one standalone script.

This is the structure on files:

[image]

My index.html has containers for load the templates to **Header** and **Footer**.

[image]

The Html5 of templates, for example is:

[image]

The result:

[image]